# Find $a, b, c$ based on a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, linear-transformations

We have a linear transformation $A: R_2[x] \to R_2[x]$ which works like this: $A(p(x)) = p'(x+1)$. Find all the possible values of $a, b$ and $c$ $\in R$ for which the following matrix is the transformation matrix of $A$, according to some base of $R_2[x]$.

\begin{bmatrix}
a && 1 && 0 \\
b && 0 && 1 \\
c && 0 && 0
\end{bmatrix}

I know that one base is $\{1, x, x^2\}$, but when I try to transform it, I still don't see how I should proceed. Can someone please give me an idea? Thanks

Comment: One way to do it would be to write down the matrix of $A$ in a basis you know. Then the question is what matrices of the given form are similar to that matrix.

Comment: @user49640 okay, that's a good idea. Do you have a recomendation on what the best way for finding similar matrices could be?

Comment: In this case, an easy basis to take would be $1, x, (x-1)^2/2$. Once you've done that, there are many ways to approach the problem. Certainly similar matrices must have the same characteristic polynomial, so that will give you some information about $a, b, c$. That may or may not be enough information on its own to solve the problem.

Comment: $A^3=0$ and the given matrix has characteristic polynomial $x^3-a x^2-b x - c$

Answer (score 0):

The matrix of $A$ with respect to the standard basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$ is
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & 2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}. $$
Now, with this we can find the characteristic polynomial of $A$; we find that this is
$$ \det{(A-tI)} = -t^3 $$
since $A$ is lower-diagonal. Since $(SBS^{-1})^n = SB^nS^{-1}$, the characteristic polynomial is the same for similar matrices, and so we have to have $a,b,c$ so that the characteristic polynomial of the given matrix is also $-t^3$. We find, in fact, that the characteristic polynomial of the matrix is $$ c + b t + a t^2 - t^3, $$
so the only possibility is $a=b=c=0$. Another equivalent way to look at this is that the determinant is preserved, the trace is preserved, and the trace of the square is preserved, so you can calculate these and check against a known matrix form.